# How to Make a WMI call fail?

Tags: windows-service, testing, wmi

I'm a developer but I have a question that seems belongs more in the ServerFault category than StackOverflow.

We have a production service that every so often tends to throw:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Call was canceled by the
>   message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002
>   (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))

The code that's triggering this error is using WMI to get network interface MAC addresses. I have replacement code that doesn't use WMI but we need to verify the issue before/after the change. My question then is: How can I artificially recreate the error message generated above?

Comment: Pretty sure that stopping the Windows Management Instrumentation Service would do it... but I'd question the value of such testing.

Comment: I thought of that but strangely enough that doesn't seem to do it. The program still seems to run fine.

Comment: i have the same problem, any new information on this?